# Computer screen turns off when I use a random electric switch or plug a device in my house

Tags: electrical

First of all I am in Greece, which has the EU 230V AC power network.

I have a computer screen connected to a hub which in turn goes to a power outlet in a room in my house. When I press a light switch or plug another device to any other outlet, the screen turns off and on, once. This doesn't always happen, but it happens often enough to worry me.

I connected the screen to another outlet and I managed to reproduce the problem. I measured the voltage and current output of the outlet that the hub draws and it is varies between 240-250 Volts, 1 A.

Any ideas why I am having this problem? It seems to me like it momentarily loses power. What is it causing it. Is this a problem with my house's power cables?

Comment: It might be caused by insufficient shielding or noise suppression in the power cable to the screen. My computer screen blinks off when I switch on or off a nearby fluorescent desk-lamp. It is Ok when I turn on or off any other lamp or device in the room. Switching something on creates electrical noise that can travel along power cables. This needs to be filtered out. However it probably isn't causing permanent harm, only annoyance. You can buy a cheap ferrite "choke" that clamps over the power cable to you screen, it might help (and won't do any harm)

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and ordered a ferrite choke from ebay. I will report back if this solves the issue. Thank you.